# Mdadm array showing as UUID?

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, uuid

I have an ssd with ubuntu and then 4 hdds in a mdadm array. I had to reinstall ubuntu and now am seeing the array but only mounted as the UUID and the array appears as an external drive in ubuntu. What do I need to do to get it to mount correctly again? Currently if I type:

```
"sudo mdadm --detail --scan"
```

I receive:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=MediaPC:0 UUID=8b0b8603:e3f4b802:dc78a796:8126339c
```

not sure why its showing up as md/0

```
"cat /proc/mdstat" returns


md0 : active raid6 sdb1[0] sde1[3] sdc1[1] sdd1[2]
  7813770240 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
unused devices: <none>
```

to be clear I can access the files but the drive shows up as

```
/media/username/RAID-UUID/
```

which isn't the most convenient. Before it was mounted as

```
/mnt/Raid6
```

and showed up as a normal file directory.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTI2J.png)

EDIT: Lastly, if I type

```
sudo mdadm config
```

I get a message telling me "No such file or directory"

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=d0c4a355-673f-4047-bd29-94d62f538795 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=40ED-0A22  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: What does your `/etc/fstab` say?

Comment: ahh, do I need to add something for the array into /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is not listed in `/etc/fstab`, therefore it is not automatically mounted.  If you want it to be automatically mounted in a specific location, you need to add it.

Comment: What all do I need to put in there? Like whats the format? I thought prior I had just used a command to write to the /etc/fstab, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @CharlieS, see the comment line at the top of the file, and/or use the other entries as an example.  To look up the UUID of the volume you can use `blkid`.